# SharePoint 2013 - Color Code Text in a Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jslink, calculated-column-formula

How would I color code text in a column when an overdue date threshold is reached?

I created a calculated column (# days overdue) that shows total number of days the item has been open.  When the # days overdue is greater than 30 days an exclamation mark (!) appears in the alert column.  How would I change the color of the exclamation mark to red?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the exclamation mark is the only thing that's in the Alert column then you could simply add the following CSS to a Script or Content Editor Web Part on your page:

```
.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4){
    color: red;
}
```

You might have to change the number in `nth-child(4)` to address the right column.

If the Alert column can contain different values and only an exclamation mark shall be colored red then you need a more sophisticated solution. The following JSLink code should get you started:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
    function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
        return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
    }
    function init() {
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
            Templates: {
                Fields: {
                    "Alert": {
                        View: function(ctx) {
                            if (ctx.CurrentItem["Alert"] == "!") {
                                return "<font color='red'>" + ctx.CurrentItem["Alert"] + "</font>";
                            } else {
                                return ctx.CurrentItem["Alert"];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            ListTemplateType: 100
        });
    }
    RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/colorAlertColumn.js"), init);
    init();
});
```

Here is an excellent article about CSR and how to implement it: 
[SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)